# How do I use conditional formatting to change a cell fill colour if certain information is entered

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I need to change each cell so that when I enter a specific piece of text it changes to a particular color and does not show the text

- say A1 is A which is available - I want this cell to be red fill,
- b1 is unavailable - U so I want this cell to fill yellow and so on

Answer (score 0):

Stupid trick: change the colour of the text to match the colour of the cell fill.  You won't be able to see the text anymore.

Here is a screenshot of the conditional formatting rules:

[image: Conditional Formatting Window]

Change the Applies to as you see fit.